# Toggling fullscreen and removing styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle to fullscreen when I press a button. I have created some extra styles when the window pops up but, when I try to exit using the escape key, the styles are still there. If I press the escape key after the fullscreen has exited the styles are removed. Is there a workaround. Here is the code of what I have currently

```
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");

function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (mainContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        mainContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = "#3D5A80";
        mainContainer.style.paddingTop = "40px";
    }
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/1647cbrm/) for toy

```js
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");


function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (mainContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        mainContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = "#3D5A80";
        mainContainer.style.paddingTop = "40px";
    }
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
}
    function exitHandler() {
        if (!document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
             mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
    }
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {   
     // this is nessecary so far i dont know how to attach event on esc while fullscreen on 
           
        }
    });
$('.button').click(function(){
 toggleFullScreen();
});
```

```css
#mainContainer{
  height:50vw;
  width:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainContainer'>

</div>
<button class='button'>
FS
</button>
```

Oh i guess snipped does not support fullscreen play it on **jsfiddle**

so far i just attached event when you go off from fullscreen thats all enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<div id="mainContainer" onclick="toggleFullScreen(this)" style="width:100%; height: 100%" />
<script>
var mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");

function toggleFullScreen(divObj) {
 if (divObj.requestFullscreen)    
  if (document.fullScreenElement) { 
   document.cancelFullScreen();        
  } else { 
   divObj.requestFullscreen(); 
  } 
 else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen) 
  if (document.msFullscreenElement) { 
   document.msExitFullscreen(); 
  } else { 
   divObj.msRequestFullscreen(); 
  } 
 else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen) 
  if (document.mozFullScreenElement) { 
   document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 
  } else { 
   divObj.mozRequestFullScreen(); 
  } 
 else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
  if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) { 
   document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 
  } else { 
   divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen(); 
  } 
}

function changeHandler(){                        
 var fs = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement ||  document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement;                               
 if (fs) {                                                              
  mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = "#3D5A80";
  mainContainer.style.paddingTop = "40px";               
 }                                                                      
 else {                                                                 
  mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = '';
  mainContainer.style.paddingTop = '';
 }                                                                      
}
   
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);      
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", changeHandler, false);
</script>
</html>
```